# Is a loaded question a fallacy?

Tags: logic

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loaded_question says that a loaded question = a complex question fallacy. Yet how's it a fallacy? Isn't it a logically consistent, valid (yet militant and treacherous) method?

http://www.fallacyfiles.org/loadques.html claims:

> Since a question is not an argument, simply asking a loaded question is not a fallacious argument. Rather, loaded questions are typically used to trick someone into implying something they did not intend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your source is correct, it's not a fallacious **argument** -- since as your source points out, it's not an argument.

*But* informal fallacies are not limited to problematic arguments but also to problematic techniques in many contexts of rhetoric and argumentation. Thus, it need not be logically invalid to be fallacious in usage.

In the case of a loaded question, the problem is that it's unfair to the person you are asking, because it prejudices the listener by making it so either answer presents the answerer in an unfair light and that refusing to answer places the answerer in an unfair light.

The quintessential example which William Lycan uses but so do many others is:

> Have you stopped beating your wife yet?

---

If anything, one of the biggest problems with informal fallacies is that they are more "rules of thumb" than sharply defined terms.

Comment: Would this question, despite its fallacious nautre, be subject to a true/false dichotomy, as per the Law of the Excluded Middle? Or, more simply, is there an answer to this question? It certainly doesn't seem to be the case, but I'd love a more technical answer :)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "this question"? Or better yet, clarify it and ask it as a new question.

Comment: If someone asked me "Have you stopped beating your wife?", how would it be answered?

Comment: I know that it is not a proposition, so is not constricted to the LoEM, but it is still a yes/no question that seemingly should have an answer.

Comment: If you have a question, ask it as a question -- not as a comment